# How can I refactor my React component to accept an array of errors and shows an error message if error.show = true for any one of those errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

Right now my React `Loader` **component** only accepts one error object. So if there are multiple error conditions, I have to write a conditional statements that reduces those errors down to a single error.

```js
class Loader extends Component {
  static displayName = 'Loader';

  static propTypes = {
    error: PropTypes.object,
    loaded: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    noData: PropTypes.object,
    render: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  get spinner() {
    const {
      loaded
    } = this.props;

    return <Spinner show = {!loaded
    }
    />;
  }

  get component() {
    const {
      loaded,
      noData,
      render
    } = this.props;

    if (!loaded && !this.hasError) {
      return this.spinner;
    }

    if (!loaded && this.hasError) {
      return this.serviceError;
    }

    // Handles API returning no data scenario
    if (loaded && !this.hasError && noData) {
      return this.serviceError;
    }

    return render();
  }

  get hasError() {
    const {
      error
    } = this.props;

    if (!error) {
      return false;
    }

    return error.show;
  }

  get serviceError() {
    const {
      noData
    } = this.props;

    if (this.hasError) {
      return <ServiceError / > ;
    }

    return <ServiceError { ...noData
    }
    noIcon = {
      true
    }
    />;
  }

  render() {
    return this.component;
  }
}

export default Loader;
```

How can I make so the `Loader` accepts an array of errors and shows an error message if error.show = true for any one of those errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to check if one or more elements meet your criteria. Something like this should get you headed in the right direction:

```js
class Loader extends Component {
  static displayName = 'Loader';

  static propTypes = {
    error: PropTypes.array,
    loaded: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    noData: PropTypes.object,
    render: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  get spinner() {
    const {
      loaded
    } = this.props;

    return <Spinner show = {!loaded
    }
    />;
  }

  get component() {
    const {
      loaded,
      noData,
      render
    } = this.props;

    if (!loaded && !this.hasError) {
      return this.spinner;
    }

    if (!loaded && this.hasError) {
      return this.serviceError;
    }

    // Handles API returning no data scenario
    if (loaded && !this.hasError && noData) {
      return this.serviceError;
    }

    return render();
  }

  get hasError() {
    const {
      error
    } = this.props;

    return error.some(el => el.show === true);
  }

  get serviceError() {
    const {
      noData
    } = this.props;

    if (this.hasError) {
      return <ServiceError / > ;
    }

    return <ServiceError { ...noData
    }
    noIcon = {
      true
    }
    />;
  }

  render() {
    return this.component;
  }
}

export default Loader;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`errors: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)`](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types#usage) to accept a list of errors or [`PropTypes.oneOf([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)])`](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types#usage) if you want to accept both.

Then, you can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if any of those is true like `this.props.errors.some(error => error.show === true)`.

If you're using lodash, try [`_.some(this.props.errors, { show: true })`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#some).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, but you can just iterate and return when show is true.

```js
class Loader extends Component {
  static displayName = 'Loader';

  static propTypes = {
    error: PropTypes.array,
    loaded: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    noData: PropTypes.object,
    render: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  get spinner() {
    const { loaded } = this.props;

    return <Spinner show={!loaded} />;
  }

  get component() {
    const { loaded, noData, render } = this.props;

    if (!loaded && !this.hasError) {
      return this.spinner;
    }

    if (!loaded && this.hasError) {
      return this.serviceError;
    }

    // Handles API returning no data scenario
    if (loaded && !this.hasError && noData) {
      return this.serviceError;
    }

    return render();
  }

  get hasError() {
    const { error } = this.props;

    if (!error) {
      return false;
    }
    // Return when at least one error is true
    for (let i = 0; i < error.length; i++) {
      if (error[i].show) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  get serviceError() {
    const { noData } = this.props;

    if (this.hasError) {
      return <ServiceError />;
    }

    return <ServiceError {...noData} noIcon={true} />;
  }

  render() {
    return this.component;
  }
}

export default Loader;
```